# Разница в применении атрибутов [InverseProperty] и [ForeignKey]

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Обьясните, пожалуйста, максимально простыми словами, в чем же разница между `[InverseProperty]` и `[ForeignKey]`, ведь оба атрибута устанавливают однозначную связь между сущностями `Entity FW`. Так когда лучше использовать первый, а когда второй атрибут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ForeignKey` - используются когда две сущности имеют одну связь. 
`[InverseProperty]` - когда таких связей несколько, думаю не так уж часто такое происходит, но к примеру в документации рассматривается ситуация связи сущностей Учитель - Курс. Конкретно там появляется две таблицы одинаковых сущностей - онлайн курсы и курсы в классе. Возникает такая ситуация. На мой взгляд она несколько надуманная, ну да ладно.

```
public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OnlineTeacher")]
    public int? OnlineTeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher OnlineTeacher { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClassRoomTeacher")]
    public int? ClassRoomTeacherId { get; set; }
    public Teacher ClassRoomTeacher { get; set; }
}

public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("OnlineTeacher")]
    public ICollection<Course> OnlineCourses { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ClassRoomTeacher")]
    public ICollection<Course> ClassRoomCourses { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: А что было бы если бы мы просто использовали `ForeignKey` в таблице `Teacher`  вместо `InverseProperty` ?

Comment: Кинет исключение

Comment: Таблица `УЧИТЕЛЬ` может иметь несколько связей с каждой из нескольких таблиц или `InverseProperty` работает только для нескольких связей между `УЧИТЕЛЬ` и еще одной таблицой ?

Comment: Ну я так понял, что связь один ко многим сущностям из разных таблиц. Вообще лично с такими ситуациями не связывался, вещь специфическая, так что может кто еще мимо проходить будет и объяснит лучше...